# Delta method in a multinomial logistic regression

Tags: logistic, multinomial-logit, delta-method, robust-standard-error

I am estimating a multinomial logistic model with R (package "mlogit"). I use the estimated coefficients to get the estimated odds and then I apply the Delta Method (package "deltamethod") to get robust standard errors. 
So far, I am following the instructions [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/deltamethod.htm).
Then, I divide the estimated coefficients by the new standard errors to get new t-values and apply `2*(1-pnorm(abs(tvalues), mean = 0, sd = 1))` to get p-values.

The problem is that after applying the Delta Method, some variables that have been highly significant before the transformation become insignificant. What is the cause? Did I make a mistake somewhere?